# ¿Como eliminar un registro de una tabla con ajax en el framework de laravel?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel, ajax

Buenos días necesito ayuda con un eliminar para Laravel con ajax.

Este es el controllador:

```
class FormulacionController extends Controller
{    
    public function eliminarObjetivo($id) {
        // delete
        $respuestaverbo = respuesta_verbo::find($id);
        $respuestaverbo->delete();
        return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Articulo Eliminado'
        ]);    
   }
}
```

Esta es la ruta:

```
Route::get('eliminarObjetivo/{id}', 'FormulacionController@eliminarObjetivo')- 
>name('eliminarObjetivo');
```

El nombre de la vista y lo que contiene:

```
FormulacionAsociar.blade.php

<a id="eliminarObjetivo" onclick="eliminarObjetivo({{$Objetivos->id_respustaverbos}})"  
class="boton2_eliminar2"><span class="icon-bin"></span><div id="hover_eliminar"></div></a>
```

Y el ajax que se llama desde la vista:

```
function eliminarObjetivo(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/eliminarObjetivo/' + id,
        type: 'DELETE',
        success: function(result) {
        // bla bla
        }
     });
}
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema? ¿Eso te dá algún error?

Comment: Me sale en la consola: 
app.js:1 DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8000/eliminarObjetivo/41 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Algo que veo raro es que la ruta en Laravel tiene método `get`, y a la llamada ajax le pones un atributo `type: 'DELETE'`. ¿A que se debe eso?

Comment: Si coloco get en el ajax tambien me devuelve el mismo error, de not found, lo del delete simplemente lo vi en un tutorial no se si es trascendental o no

Comment: Si, el registro existe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenes que poner la ruta en modo POST no en GET y pone type:post en el metodo ajax, el metodo Delete se puede utilizar pero para utilizarlo tenes que hacer el form dentro del boton,

Ponelo asi

```
Route::get('eliminarObjetivo/{id}', 'FormulacionController@eliminarObjetivo')->name('eliminarObjetivo');
```

y tambien el metodo ajax cambialo asi

```
function eliminarObjetivo(id) {
$.ajax({
    url: '/eliminarObjetivo/' + id,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(result) {
    // bla bla
    }
 });
```

}

Si te tira un error el metodo quizas no tengas el {{ csrf_token() }}

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que enviar por metodo `post` y enviar en `data`: `_method: "delete"`. Si te pide el token le añades `_token: "<tu csrf_token>"`

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/eliminarObjetivo/' + id,
    method: 'POST',
    data:{
       "_method": "delete",
       "_token": "<tu csrf_token>" // puede que esto sea opcional
    }
    success: function(result) {
    // bla bla
    }
});
```

La ruta la debes poner como `::delete`, puedes usar `::post` y quitar `data` en el ajax, pero no es una buena práctica

```
Route::delete('eliminarObjetivo/{id}', 'FormulacionController@eliminarObjetivo')
    ->name('eliminarObjetivo');
```

con eso debería funcionar.

Comment: Ahora me sale en la consola: 
FormulacionAsociar:2186 Uncaught TypeError: eliminarObjetivo is not a function
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (FormulacionAsociar:2186)